# How can I separate logic and presentation code when building a calendar?

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, design-patterns, logic

Ok, we have a page. A very simple one. Let's call it `page.php`. It will have a controller and a view. The controller will just catch up some GET variables and print them out in the beginning of that page, the view will show up an header a footer and a paragraph that will contain the GET variables from the controller.

Now let's imagine we want to add a calendar. You think it's good and easy. Well, it seems not at all to me.

The calendar is made up of `<table><tbody>X</tbody></table>` which is pure HTML and a logic PHP script (that will fill the `X`) that will create (based on the `time()`stamp of the current date and time) the month dates and and numbers.

Now I encounter an ethic problem: How could I divide logic and view of that calendar?

The block of code that will create the dates will print `<td>` and `<tr>` elaborating the `time()`. But if the logic prints HTML isn't it bad? I think so, because you loose that comfortably think called "division of logic and view" that is typical of the MVC pattern.

At the same time if we take all the calendar logic to the controller and we just send to the view and array of dates (with coordinates X and Y to tell him the place where to put the first date of the month) the view will still need of elaborate the array and will became logic as well.

How could I really divide logic and view from this calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply iterating over an array in a view is perfectly fine and not a violation of the MVC pattern. The logic happens in the controller where you populate the array. Even better would probably be to put the logic into a Model named Calendar.php and simply initialize it in the controller to pass it to the view.

Answer (score -1):

u can put logic codes in a php file and assign the result to the variables that will show in view file (for example array)

in view file you can echo the variables and put html tags easily.

Comment: Why is that best advice? That rather sounds like a total random suggestion. Why ZF and not some other framework? Why a framework at all?

Comment: you can search for ZF benefits, if u use of ZF you can manage view , control , model easily. ZF is depend on MVC structure. there is many library that u can use . at first it take some time for learning but after that u can develop your proj at less time

Comment: And I can only do that with ZF? And not also with another framework, like Symfony? Or Zeta Components? Or even without a framework at all? It's not like MVC is rocket science. Like I said, your suggestion seems completely random.

Comment: ok, Gordon. i edited that. u must not use of ZF , never :P :D